# React radio not resetting the values

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to reactjs. I have radio buttons that say UserA, UserB, UserC, and User D. I have multiple permission for UserA based on sub-selection of radio buttons(Like Admin, Editor, User). Similarly, for UserD I can have only one permission like SuperAdmin. Whenever I select UserD, it should set the permission to 'Super Admin' which is working. But If I select another radio button, User D is not unselecting.

I believe it is because I am using the name as 'permission' on both the input fields(User D and UserA Admin sub option) which is not resetting the values in the state.

Here is the [codepen](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-part6-form-with-inputs-checkbox-radio-button-dro-9nknlf?embed=1&file=Form.js) for your reference. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Why is the logic so complex? What's the actual requirement? I can see permission having two values "admin" and "superAdmin". The logic that you have used is really confusing. It would be better if you can add some more detailed explanation of the actual logic.

Comment: Sorry if my description is confusing you.  If you see the codepen link, I have multiple radio buttons.  If I select the User D first and then select any other radio button, then the User D option should deselect by default which is not happening in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have all input[radio-button]'s structure similar. You must be updating the state based on a condition. This code worked for me based on the given requirement. I have made some minor changes to the `input userD` and `setState` method. I hope this resolves your problem.

```
export default function Form() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    user: '',
    testRequest: false,
    permission: ''
  });

  const [disableuserA, setdisableuserA] = React.useState(false);
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState('');

  function handleChange(e) {
    const value =
      e.target.type === 'checkbox' ? e.target.checked : e.target.value;

    setState({
      ...state,
      [e.target.name]: value,
      ...(e.target.name == 'user' &&
        e.target.value == 'userD' && { permission: 'superAdmin' })
    });
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  }
    
  
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="testRequest"
              value={value}
              onClick={() => setdisableuserA(!disableuserA)}
              checked={state.testRequest}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
            Enable this to hide the User A option
          </div>
          <div className="heading">user</div> <br />
          <input
            disabled={disableuserA}
            type="radio"
            name="user"
            value="userA"
            checked={selected === 'userA' || selected === 'admin'}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          UserA
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="user"
            value="userB"
            checked={state.user === 'userB'}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          UserB
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="user"
            value="userC"
            checked={state.user === 'userC'}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          UserC
          <input
            type="radio"
            name="user"
            value="userD"
            checked={state.user === 'userD'}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          UserD
          <br /> <hr />
          <div
            aria-hidden={
              selected !== 'userA' &&
              selected !== 'admin' &&
              selected !== 'editor' &&
              selected !== 'publisher'
                ? true
                : false
            }
          >
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="permission"
              value="admin"
              checked={state.permission === 'admin'}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />{' '}
            Admin
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="permission"
              value="editor"
              checked={state.permission === 'editor'}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />{' '}
            Editor
            <input
              type="radio"
              name="permission"
              value="publisher"
              checked={state.permission === 'publisher'}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />{' '}
            Publisher
          </div>
          <br /> <br />
          <button type="submit" className="btn-default btn">
            Submit{' '}
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, null, 3)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactjs-part6-form-with-inputs-checkbox-radio-button-dro-p3ebju?file=Form.js)